# modifying a queue sequence in TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, queue

In SQL Server 2008 I have a table "Q" of people in a FIFO queue:

```
Person     Position
  23          1
  49          5
  108         2
  .           .
  .           .
```

So, of course I can view the queue using

```
  SELECT * FROM Q ORDER BY Position
```

I need to be able to move people up and down in the queue. I know I can do it RBAR in s stored procedure, but I'd like be able to do it in a single query if possible. The requirement is

```
   move person 'x' to position y
```

i.e. move 'x' ahead of the person in position y and move that person and everyone behind back one

The algorithm is:

1. find position # of 'x'
2. for each person - except 'x' - whose position is >= 'y' increment position by one
3. set position of 'x' to y.

Is there such a query?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- linked list (`Id`, `PrevId`), but `Position` now is something that needs to be calculated or recalculated for each operation
- doubly linked list (`Id`, `PrevId`, `NextId`); same as above
- `position` as `float`, when an insertion is happening new `position` is calculated as the average of previous and next positions; but eventually you will run out of precision, so you will have to maintain it by redistributing values more evenly

Now, back to your question. One query you say? Not gonna happen.